# How to connect my docker image to my kubernetes cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have a simple play project, and I created a docker image for it.

I created the image like:

in my circle.yml I added:

```
deployment:
  feature:
    branch: /.*/
    commands:
      - docker login -e admin@something.com -u ${ART_USER} -p ${ART_KEY} crp-docker-docker-local.someartifactory.com
      - sbt -DBUILD_NUMBER="${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}" docker:publish
```

Now in my jfrog account I have the image name for this project, and in my controller.yml I added this specific image.

But now I have created kubernetes clusters with 4 minions machines and one master machine, and I want to know how do I connect this docker image to this cluster to run it?

thanksss

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl run <app name> --image=<image name from jfrog>`

If you want to automatically fetch the image name and start the container, you can run a special container that will fetch the image names